# Grub Do not Load Dual Boot after ShutDown

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, grub2, windows, shutdown

I have Dual Boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10 .
When I shut down/restart the Ubuntu I get the the start screen but GRUB wont load . If I Go to BIOS and then goto save changes and exit , without changing anything , GRUB would load .
When I shut down/restart from Windows I am not even able to go BIOS , so I take the battery of the laptop out and then put it back again . Then again GRUB wouldn`t load , Then I go to BIOS and follow the same procedure again .
I was able to normally turn on the laptop earlier even after dual boot , but now it is creating problems .
Please HELP so that I am able to restart / shut down laptop and turn it on normally .
PLEASE HELP .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your bootloader is corrupted.

Here is the official [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) to reparing your bootloader.

Comment: good it helped me too

Comment: You should also disable fast-start in Windows 8, if you have not done so already.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but earlier after dual boot , laptop was properly functioning after running boot repair . But after some time it stopped working properly , I have also tried running boot repair now also , but its of no use . http://paste.ubuntu.com/7669279/

Comment: Apparently, your issue stems from how Windows doesn't fully shuts down but rather suspends volumes upon 'shutdown' thus breaking your bootloader (more or less). This superuser [thread/answer](http://superuser.com/a/589025/332183) seems to be exactly what you need. :)


BTW, this does exactly what Charles Green said in his comment above, disables fast-start.

Comment: Thanks , I will definitely try that . But even when I shutdown/restart from Ubuntu the problem is there . What to do to solve that .

Comment: I can't say for sure what your problem is then other than, maybe Windows 8 is configured to fire up certain partitions/file systems at boot (for fast-start), regardless of your Ubuntu install, which may then overwrite or take precedence over your bootloader. Hopefully, this is so because then disabling fast-start as stated above, will fix everything. Unfortunately, this comment is little more than conjecture. I know Windows 8 has implemented a **lot** of boot level changes but I do not personally own any Windows 8 devices.

Comment: I have turned off fast startup , but still GRUB do not load after shutdown/restart , But now I am able to go to BIOS .

Comment: I would do one boot repair post turning off fast-start and if that still doesn't fix it feel free to comment back.

Comment: That doesn`t help . Here is the new link http://paste.ubuntu.com/7688867/

Comment: Hey user, is there a particular reason you have so many Windows partitions? Also, I can't say this for sure but having your bootloader within extended partition (which you had to create due to how many Windows partitions you have), all the way in sda6 may be your culprit. The paste does state (last line) that your boot files are quite deep into your partitioning scheme and thus may cause a problem.

Maybe if you have Ubuntu as your first 1, 2 partitions then Windows following that OR both installs within the extended partition your problem wouldn't exist; just conjecture.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I do not know why there are so many partitions . I just installed Windows 8.1 normally and then installed ubuntu followed by boot repair . can  it be due to the number of hard disk partitions ?

Comment: Well, the number of partitions is why you needed an extended partition for your Ubuntu install. (which it probably created automatically) As for if that is the problem, the paste you linked does state (last line) that your boot files are quite deep into your partitioning scheme and thus be the problem. Might not be though. Here is a link to a guide to dual booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu. We may have only turned off fast start and forgot to turn off secure boot. [Guide](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)